# How do I create Joomla style modules in my own custom cms?

Tags: php, module

I know it's a not a good idea to re-create a CMS especially these days but...this is a special requirement. I am creating a custom management system for a company. My question is
How can I create a modular CMS where I can load in modules that have "Their Own" JavaScript and CSS files without conflicting with the already loaded modules and header scripts. I want to be able to create this sort of structure:

App
- Modules
   - Module 1 
     - JS
     - CSS
   - Module 2 
     - JS
     - CSS

and the load them like this:

Home.php

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
loadModule('module1', 'position');
loadModule('module2', 'position');
include 'footer.php';
```

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something like this:

[build a plugin system with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217659/build-a-plugin-system-with-php)

and this:

https://code.google.com/p/phphooks/